# HTML tags missing when SELECT from MySQL (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter with MySQL database. What the script does is it takes some HTML code containing the HTML tags, insert them into the database and then retrieves the HTML code later in time.

**Problem:** I notice that all HTML tags, upon selecting rows from MySQL tables, are missing with the exception of `<br />`

Is Codeigniter/MySQL removing the HTML tags somewhere between retrieving the code, passing it from controller to model, and the model inserting the HTML code into a MySQL table column? How can I prevent it from removing HTML tags for just this specific situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like an issue with the initial insertion via a text editor.

> Text editors insert allot of style=“anything” and the xss_clean()
>   method will strip those. Use html purifier for your editor content and
>   xss_clean() for all the other fields.

Source: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/196303/

Comment: is it possible to set the xss filter to false only for that query? else i have to add true to all other querys.