# Codeigniter html tags from database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have tables in my database wich store html tags like

```
<b>Test</b>
 description
<u>some text</u>
```

i can see the tags are saved in the database.

when i try to retrive the data like:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('collecties');
$this->db->where('id' , $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

i get the right data but without the tags.

How can i get the tags from the database.

**Edit**
I have read :
[HTML tags missing when SELECT from MySQL (Codeigniter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415853/html-tags-missing-when-select-from-mysql-codeigniter?rq=1)

But im 100% sure the tags are in the database because i view it with mysql workbench.

Comment: Hrm. That seems odd to me, I would think the problem would lie somewhere else in your application (something on the view side). Can you try a `var_dump($query->row())` to verify the tags are actually there?

Comment: I view the database with mysql workbench so im 100% sure they are in the database. if i use the var_dump it isn't showing any tags

Comment: Gotcha, now that I think of it, I remember having a similar problem long ago when I first started using code igniter. I remember fixing it by disabling code igniter's built in xss_clean (which is overly blunt imo). Try setting the `global_xss_filtering` attribute to `false` in your code igniter config file

Comment: @mituw16 Is it possible to only disable xxs filtering for this query, else i have to add the xss filtering to every other query. I set it to false but it is still not working, by the way isnt it for get and post only and not for querys?

Comment: xss_clean works on Inputs, so if it's enabled you remove the tags *when inserting* , not while selecting...

Comment: @DamienPirsy thats wat i was thinking too